# Cannot select rows after tableView.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

In my application, I have a tableview that constantly (every 5 seconds) needs updating. To do this, I have set a timer which runs a method updating the data source (array) and calling the tableView.reloadData() method immediately afterwards. Unfortunately, a problem arises after the reloadData() method is called, one in which I cannot select a row without first scrolling! It's very strange. All I have to do is slightly make the table view scroll, and I can select cells again. Help!

*viewDidLoad*

```
DataHandler.updateCustomers() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.updateTable()
        })
}
let _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "updateData", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

*updateData*

```
func updateData(){

    DataHandler.updateCustomers() {
        if (self.activeIDs.indexPathForSelectedRow == nil){
            self.activeIDs.reloadData()
        }
    }
    print("Data updated")
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dispatch to main just like you did in the first closure also in the second one before you execute self.activeIDs.reloadData()

Comment: Hey, thanks! That fixed it. :)